# Modal Dialog box with on/off and min/max button in Jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog, lightbox

I need modal dialog box in which I can open forms and other html pages. It should have on/off and min/max button. Could anybody suggest me any link for the same. I am not getting this type of widget anywhere.

Comment: How did it go, did you find something in the end?

Comment: @Scozzard no i didnt find yet anything...

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery plugin [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) is pretty effective. I have used it before and am quite sure it should provide the functionality you require.

Comment: Yes you can set the height and width of the window using the minHeight and minWidth properties (check out the 6th example on the plugins homepage)